# Disable/enable logging in Magento from database

Tags: php, magento

I know that to enable logging through admin you can go:
System > Configuration > Advanced > Developer > Log Settings > Enable

But is there any way to enable it through database? As I don't have access to admin.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

All settings appearing in System / Configuration are stored in the `core_config_data` table.

The one you're searching is `dev/log/active`.

Be careful, in this table, you can have different values for each stores

Comment: If it's missing there, should I insert it?

Comment: Yep you can (the default (false)  is stored in a XML file). but be sure of what you're doing

Comment: `INSERT INTO your_database_name.core_config_data (scope, scope_id, path, value) VALUES ( 'default', '0', 'dev/log/active', '1');`

Answer (score 4):

Change  variable values in the file lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php to

```
$_debug               = true;
$_logQueryTime        = 0.05;
$_logAllQueries       = true;
$_logCallStack        = false;
$_debugFile           = 'var/debug/pdo_mysql.log';
```

This will print out the sql queries